# python: compare two timestamp in different dates

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe, the index is timestamp format with '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`'
Now i want to divide this data frame into two parts.
one is the data with time **before** `12pm('YYYY-MM-DD 12:00:00')` everyday 
another is the data with time **after** 12pm for everyday.

I'm just stuck with this question for several days. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you expect as output?  Two dataframes, one with all the morning rows and one with all the afternoon rows?

Comment: Yes. one data frame with daily morning data and another one with daily afternoon data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DatetimeIndex (and if you don't, `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` should work to get one), then you can access `.hour`, e.g. `df.index.hour`, and select using that:

```
>>> df.head()
                     A
2015-01-01 00:00:00  0
2015-01-01 01:00:00  1
2015-01-01 02:00:00  2
2015-01-01 03:00:00  3
2015-01-01 04:00:00  4
>>> morning = df[df.index.hour < 12]
>>> afternoon = df[df.index.hour >= 12]
>>> morning.head()
                     A
2015-01-01 00:00:00  0
2015-01-01 01:00:00  1
2015-01-01 02:00:00  2
2015-01-01 03:00:00  3
2015-01-01 04:00:00  4
>>> afternoon.head()
                      A
2015-01-01 12:00:00  12
2015-01-01 13:00:00  13
2015-01-01 14:00:00  14
2015-01-01 15:00:00  15
2015-01-01 16:00:00  16
```

You could also use `groupby`, e.g. `df.groupby(df.index.hour < 12)`, but that seems like overkill here.  If you wanted a more complex division that might be the way to go, though.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I have tried your suggestion, but it shows 'TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable'  The index.hour shows: array([ 9,  9,  9, ..., 18, 18, 18], dtype=int32)

Comment: That makes it seem like you tried something like `DataFrame[df.index.hour < 12]` or something, that is, you're indexing the *type*, not your dataframe.  What was your exact command?

Comment: And just curious, how can i do if I want to divide the dataframe by using daily 12:01:01 as a breakpoint? @DSM